# Regular expression for 1(2),3,4(5,6(7,8),9),10

Tags: c#, regex

### Prologue:

**Input string: `1(2),3,4(5,6(7,8),9),10`**

I am using C# and I would want to eventually get a `List<foo>` from the above expression

```
public class foo
{
    public int bar { get; set; }
    public List<foo> listOfFoo { get; set; }
}
```

I can achieve the task by writing some validations and parsing character by character, but would like to know a better way. Lesser the code, lesser the bugs they say ;)

### Query

I am looking for a regular expression for validating and possibly capturing information in a string like

```
1(2),3,4(5,6(7,8),9),10
```

The string is basically a set of numbers separated by comma. But a number can have some sub expressions for it using parenthesis `(` `)`

What I want to fetch from the string is a graph like

```
1
    2
3
4
    5
    6
        7
        8
    9
10
```

I have very little idea about reg-ex. I can read & understand most of them, but writing one I find really tough

Looking for someone to tell me if something like this is at all achievable using RegEx. If so, what should be the approach? I can see that I would need a recursive expression, any links or examples would be of great help. Someone willing to give me the RegEx itself would be icing on the cake :)

Comment: this is not regex task

Comment: +1 not a regex task; use/write a proper parser

Comment: This sounds similar to [trying to parse html (tree like structure) with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks guys for the very quick feedback!! I will indeed write a parser. Will keep the question open for the future though

Comment: To get a regular expression, its necessary to prove that such language is regular (a machine with finite states can accept strings such that)

Comment: @ArnaldoGaspar That is true for theoretical regex; in practice the regex engines we use in our various programming languages add capabilities that exceed such a mandate. For example, theoretical regex does not have a concept of lookahead/lookbehind. PHP even supports the concept of recursive matching.

Answer (score 2):

.NET regex has [balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) which allow you to count and match balanced parenthesis like in this case.

For that you can use an expression like this:

```
(?x)                 # ignore spaces and comments
^
(?:
    (?<open> \( )*   # open++
    \d+
    (?<-open> \) )*  # open--
    (?:
        , (?!\z)     # match a , but not at end of string
    |   \z           # or end of string
    )
)+
\z
(?(open) (?!) )      # fail if unbalanced (open > 0)
```

This would validate but not parse the string. To build a tree like you desire you have to use a parser I believe.